# Resize: Command not found MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, resize, homebrew, xterm

I am currently running a newly installed copy of MacOS Sierra and noticed that while running the command `resize -s 24 86` term says resize: command not found

I have tried running `brew install resize`

Even brew's repository does not have it

Expected: The term window should resize to 86x24

Actual: Resize: command not found

Answer (score 1):

[`resize`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) is a utility written for [`xterm`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#more_info), and is commonly bundled with that program.  If you install [`XQuartz`](https://www.xquartz.org/), you'll have `resize`.

All of brew's X-related packages depend upon `XQuartz`, so you'd have to start there anyway.

Comment: Very well, I totally forgot that mac doesn't come shipped with X-Quartz and yeah it makes sense since resize command effects the GUI, so it should be a part of X-Quartz.

Thanks. Now I feel happy and embarrassed at the same time.